# Avoiding repetition in nested If Else statements

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I am trying to manage a command line statement via `if`/`else`. The code below works, but it feels to long. Especially the repeated `else` statements in each of the nested `if`/`else` levels. Is there a way to simply leave any of the inner levels and defer to the outer `else` statement to neaten the code? There are two functions that are called, `rndm()` and `spcfc()`. I have not included these, as I really just want to tidy up the main function. I know this function should be all indented under `def main()`, but that is how it pasted in from my file.

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        txt = input("Input: ")
        rndm(txt)
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font":
            if sys.argv[2] in figlet.getFonts():
                txt = input("Input: ")
                spcfc(txt)
            else:
                print("Invalid usage")
                sys.exit
        else:
            print("Invalid usage")
            sys.exit
    else:
        print("Invalid usage")
        sys.exit
```

Comment: FWIW, use the `argparse` module and you get those checks for free. Also, `sys.exit` ain't doing anything without calling it.

Comment: If you're in the `if` clause, then, by definition, `else` clause should NOT happen.

Comment: You can move the nested ifs in a separate function which returns on success (from the innermost if) and prints the error (and exits) after that code (only executed if no success before).

Comment: @deceze. If you are saying I should import sys first when you say call it, then I did import it in the original code. Sorry I didn't show that here. I was unaware of the 'argparse' module. Thank you

Comment: No, I’m saying you need to *call* the `sys.exit` function like so: `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the nested `if`s using `and` logic.

```
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        txt = input("Input: ")
        rndm(txt)

    if (len(sys.argv) == 3) and (sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font") and (sys.argv[2] in figlet.getFonts()):
        txt = input("Input: ")
        spcfc(txt)
        
    else:
        print("Invalid usage")
        sys.exit()
```

Also, as you can see here, your nested else repetitions are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about logic, but was not sure if I could group using parenthesis. This simplifies my code tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

See @deceze's comment, but otherwise (and concept also applicable to cases where you don't have a free solution already) you can do something like this?

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        txt = input("Input: ")
        rndm(txt)
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font":
            if sys.argv[2] in figlet.getFonts():
                txt = input("Input: ")
                spcfc(txt)
                return
    print("Invalid usage")
    sys.exit()
```

Note that a benefit of using this approach is that it could work with more complex branching too...

Comment: Thank you. This worked well. I was unaware of using the 'return' statement except when returning something from a function. Can I ask, what exactly is your return statement doing here? I assume it simply defaults to the 1st level of the function and prints the invalid usage txt?

Comment: `return` just ends the function execution anywhere it's reached. It doesn't jump out of the block (e.g. like a `break`) it really exits the function (but not the entire program altogether like `exit()`). When "nothing" is returned, a `None` is actually returned by default (which you can ignore). So here if all `if` pass `spcfc(txt)` gets called and then the function stops (returns). But otherwise the execution just skips the failed `if` check, never sees any `return` and so eventually reaches the  `print("Invalid usage")` instruction.